# How can I automatically and efficiently group by column and count distinct values on another column within that group when data has thousands of rows?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Here is some data generated using R:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)

tibble(A = round(rnorm(10, 20, 2)),
       B = round(rnorm(10, 100, 2))) %>% 
  group_by(B) %>% 
  mutate(C = n_distinct(A)) %>%  # count distinct A per B
  arrange(B, A) %>% 
  write_csv("small_example.csv")

tibble(A = round(rnorm(5000, 10000, 1000)),
       B = round(rnorm(5000, 50000, 1000))) %>% 
  group_by(B) %>% 
  mutate(C = n_distinct(A)) %>%
  arrange(B, A) %>% 
  write_csv("big_example.csv")
```

`small_example.csv` should look something like this:

[image: small_example.csv]

I am attempting to recreate column C in column D, using VBA in Excel:

```vb
Sub UpdateFormulas()
  Dim last_row As Integer
  last_row = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  For i = 2 To last_row
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$" & last_row & "=B" & _
    i & ")/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$" & last_row & ", $A$2:$A$" & last_row & ", $B$2:$B$" _
    & last_row & ", $B$2:$B$" & last_row & "))"
  Next i
End Sub
```

This VBA procedure does exactly what it is supposed to do and it works regardless of the length of the data. However, the formula I'm using is way too slow and seems to be an O(N^2) operation. How can I efficiently update these values on demand? I'm not opposed to simpler methods, but the method must be fairly automatic.

Comment: `=BYROW(DROP(FILTER(B:B,B:B<>""),1),LAMBDA(z,COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,B:B=z)))))`

Comment: @ScottCraner It's still slow, but very cool.

Comment: Do you want this to be a formula in excel or could you do the calculation of Column c in vba? If you did it in vba and then into the values it would likely be way quicker and wouldn’t need to constantly recalculate

Comment: @InjuredCoding The cells do not need to use a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using `Dictionary` improves efficiency
- 1000 rows sample data takes less than 1 sec

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim oDicB, oDicAB
    Dim sKeyB As String, sKeyAB As String
    Set oDicB = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set oDicAB = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngData = Range("A2:C" & lastRow)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        arrData(i, 1) = CStr(arrData(i, 1))
        arrData(i, 2) = CStr(arrData(i, 2))
        sKeyB = arrData(i, 2)
        sKeyAB = arrData(i, 1) & "|" & arrData(i, 2)
        If Not oDicAB.exists(sKeyAB) Then
            oDicAB(sKeyAB) = ""
            If Not oDicB.exists(sKeyB) Then
                oDicB(sKeyB) = 1
            Else
                oDicB(sKeyB) = oDicB(sKeyB) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKeyB = arrData(i, 2)
        If oDicB.exists(sKeyB) Then
            arrData(i, 3) = oDicB(sKeyB)
        End If
    Next
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Running Unique Count By Groups

**M365 Dynamic Array Formula**

```
=LET(data,A2:B23,uCol,1,gCol,2,
    ud,CHOOSECOLS(data,uCol),
    gd,CHOOSECOLS(data,gCol),
    g,UNIQUE(gd),
XLOOKUP(gd,g,BYROW(g,LAMBDA(r,
    ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(ud,gd=r)))))))
```

[image]

**Apply Using VBA**

```vb
Sub UpdateFormulas()
  
    Const SRC_FIRST_ROW_RANGE As String = "A2:B2"
    Const SRC_UNIQUE_COLUMN As Long = 1
    Const SRC_GROUP_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "D"
    Const TAB_DEL As String = "    "
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim srg As Range
    
    With ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_ROW_RANGE)
        Set srg = .Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = srg.Cells(1).EntireRow.Columns(DST_COLUMN)
    
    Dim dFormula2 As String: dFormula2 = "=LET(data," & srg.Address(0, 0) & _
        ",uCol," & SRC_UNIQUE_COLUMN & ",gCol," & SRC_GROUP_COLUMN & "," _
        & vbLf & TAB_DEL & "ud,CHOOSECOLS(data,uCol)," _
        & vbLf & TAB_DEL & "gd,CHOOSECOLS(data,gCol)," _
        & vbLf & TAB_DEL & "g,UNIQUE(gd)," _
        & vbLf & "XLOOKUP(gd,g,BYROW(g,LAMBDA(r," _
        & vbLf & TAB_DEL & "ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(ud,gd=r)))))))"
    
    'Debug.Print dFormula2
    
    dcell.Formula2 = dFormula2
  
End Sub
```

Comment: For others coming here, this solution works well enough. taller's solution is faster.